# C++ operator<< and >> methods in the header file, done very wrong

Tags: c++, operators, istream, ostream

I have this code in my header file and Ive got loads of errors on the ostream and istream lines. One error is "missing ";" before "&"" and im confuzzled, im new to this sorry

```
#pragma once

class ArrayIntStorage
{
public:
    void readFromFile();
    bool setReadSort(bool);
    void sortStd();
    void sortOwn();

    ArrayIntStorage(void);
    ~ArrayIntStorage(void);
};  

ostream& operator<< (ostream &out, const ArrayIntStorage &a);
istream& operator>> (istream &in, ArrayIntStorage &b);
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you just need to do

```
    #include <ostream>
    #include <istream>
```

then place a std namespace qualifier in front of them on those lines, ie:

```
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out,...)
```

Comment: @Giovanni `ios` = iostreams `fwd` = forward, in other words: forward declarations (not the full definitions) of the standard iostreams.

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear to me the context this code appears in but the error suggests that these declarations appear before `ostream` and `istream` are defined.

Are you including the proper header files in the proper order?

Answer (score 1):

You omitted includes:

```
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
```

Note: all the standard types like `istream`, `ostream` live within a namespace called `std`. So in order to be able to use them you need to either:

- prefix them with `std::` or
- use the namespace (`using namespace std;`). This is a very bad practice for a header file as it may cause naming clashes in the header files that are included later on.

Comment: `istream` and `ostream` are not defined in `iostream`. `iostream` is for things like `cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, and `clog`.

Comment: One shouldn't put `using namespace` in a header file. It can bring a lot of stuff into the global scope that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Ok, I omitted the fact it's a header file. I'll add the corrections.

Comment: @Fred That may have been the original intent (or not, it depends on which committee member you talk to), but all implementations of <iostream> have always included everything, and the standard has been changed to bring it in line with existing implementations.

Comment: @James: It would pretty much have to pull in `<iosfwd>` to define what it has to define, I imagine. But why not just use `<iosfwd>` directly and skip the stuff you don't need?

Comment: @Fred My interpretation of the original intent was that it would just include `<iosfwd>`, and nothing more.  All implementations, however, also included `<istream>` and `<ostream>`, and this is what C++11 will require.  In my own code, I follow the policy you seem to be recommending: I'll use `<iosfwd>` in headers, and only `<istream>` or `<ostream>`, if that's what I need.  It's actually fairly rare for me to include `<iostream>`.

Comment: @James: Yes, I see in the draft standard that I have (n2461.pdf) that `<istream>` and `<ostream>` (among others) are included in `<iostream>`. Interesting. Anyway, I think this has been a productive discussion.  8v)

Answer (score 0):

Add the iostream include and Put the method prototype inside the class and declare it friend. I can't give more details since I am replying from my mobile.

Here is a link: Operator-Overloading/Classlevelostreamoperatorandistreamoperator.htm">http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Cpp/0200_Operator-Overloading/Classlevelostreamoperatorandistreamoperator.htm

Comment: `istream` and `ostream` are not defined in `iostream`. `iostream` is for things like `cin`, `cout`, `cerr`, and `clog`.